# Fetch private repo using Github API by Basic Auth

Tags: github-api

I have a dummy app with no UI I developed to notify my mate on HipChat about pending pull requests across all our projects, even our private repos, using

My problem is I just get public repos with such request: https://api.github.com/orgs/nukomeet/repos?client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authenticating with client_id and client_secret doesn't authenticate you as a user; it just identifies the application. Since permissions are granted only to users (and not to applications), this way of authenticating with the API doesn't allow you to perform actions which require authentication.

In other words, when you provide the client_id and client_secret, you're still making unauthenticated requests but get the higher rate limit:

http://developer.github.com/v3/#unauthenticated-rate-limited-requests

To get around this problem, you'll need to authenticate using Basic Auth or OAuth:

http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication

Comment: I guess there is no way to _authenticate_ as an org?

Comment: Correct -- you can't authenticate as an org. Organizations don't have permissions themselves (only their members do), and can't perform actions on GitHub (e.g. create issues, comments, push commits, etc). All actions are performed by users, members of organizations.

Comment: A way to work around this is to create a new "machine" account and add it to the organization. You would then authenticate as this machine user when you want to authenticate as the org. By managing which teams the account is a member of -- you would have control over which permissions this machine account has.